# Apps bought on iTunes not showing up on the iPhone 4

Tags: itunes, applications, data-synchronization, icloud

An app that i buy on iTunes doesn't show up in the iPhone with iCloud unless i sync it with a cable.

Also the reverse applies. Anything bought on the iPhone doesn't show up in iTunes in the computer unless the cable is connected.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have automatic downloads enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable automatic downloads.

In iTunes: iTunes > Preferences > click on the Store tab: there you can enable automatic downloads by separately checking the boxes next to 'Music', 'Apps' and 'Books'.

On your iOS device: Settings > Store: there you'll find switches to activate automatic downloads for 'Music', 'Apps' and 'Books'.

Note: If you only enable automatic downloads in iTunes music, apps and books downloaded on your iOS device will also download in iTunes on your computer. If you only enable automatic downloads on your iOS device the reverse is true. If you want it to work in both directions you need to enable it both in iTunes and on your iOS device.

Comment: nope, didn't work. i had all these checked in both itunes and my iphone 4. wonder what the issue is ?

Comment: Have you tried logging out of the store and logging in again? Both on your iPhone and in iTunes.

Comment: (In iTunes: click on 'store' in the menu bar then click on 'log out', then log in again. On your iPhone go to "settings" > "store" > tap on you apple id and log log out, then login again.)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked.